# Bulk Update Email Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-update

I created a update trigger in Microsoft SQL Server that would email me if a date changed in a row.

Similar to this:

```
IF UPDATE(ColumnName)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @columnVal AS DATETIME

        SELECT 
            @columnVal = i.columnName
        FROM 
            inserted i JOIN deleted d on i.RowId= d.RowId;

        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
                @profile_name = 'me',
                @recipients = 'me@company.com',
                @body = 'blah blah datechange',
                @body_format = 'HTML',
                @subject = 'subject';
END
```

it worked fine for a time.
Then I switched over to batch updates and only the first row email is sent out if the date changes on multiple rows. I tried to set up a cursor to roll through the changes but I cannot get it to work,  Similar to below:

```
DECLARE @columnVal AS DATETIME

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT
        i.ColumnName
    FROM 
    inserted i JOIN deleted d on i.RowId= d.RowId;

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @columnVal

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   IF UPDATE(ColumnName)
   BEGIN
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
                @profile_name = 'me',
                @recipients = 'me@company.com',
                @body = 'blah blah datechange',
                @body_format = 'HTML',
                @subject = 'subject';
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @columnVal
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this task? Would the Update(ColumnName) function even work properly nested inside a cursor (would it actually tell me if that column was updated for that row?)

Comment: A **cursor** inside a **trigger** is a very very bad idea. A trigger should be very lean - it shouldn't do a lot of work! I would recommend to only "take a note" of who you have to send an e-mail to - but leave the actual sending of the e-mail to a separate e.g. SQL Server Agent Job which is **not** part of the trigger. Triggers are fired often and often unexpectedly - don't put a log of processing burden into them! And especially not a performance killer like a **cursor**!

Comment: UPDATE() function does not work on row basis. It returns whatever that column was updated or not, so it will be true (or false) for all your rows. You should check yourself whatever `i.ColumnName <> d.ColumnName` for each row. +everything that @marc_s said!

Comment: Unfortunately, there are some cases of "i.ColumnName <> d.ColumnName" not being good enough like when the value is updated to true from true.

Comment: And I understand the using Cursors is generally a bad idea... but how would I know which rows to "take a note" about in a  job if I do not loop through the changes?

Comment: @NetDev Using `WHERE` clause! But if you do want to send email for rows updated from true to true you don't need any filtering? All the rows in `inserted` and `deleted` tables are the ones affected by update. No more, no less. I thought the whole idea behind your `IF UPDATE()` was to filter only rows that actually changed.

Comment: @Nenad UPDATE() Is used to filter out only the rows that changed that column.  A "DATETIME => SAME DATETIME" is still a change that I care about.  All of the rows in inserted and deleted tables have been updated, but not necessarily in that column, hence the filtering... What do you mean "Using WHERE clause'?

Comment: YES necessarily in THAT column, you can't run a single update updating different columns in different rows. If `UPDATE(ColumnName)` is true, that means every row in `inserted` got that column updated - maybe with the same existing value, but it got updated.

Comment: Well said.  So the recommendation is to skip the cursor by using the where clause to rule out any columns that didn't actually change and insert into another table the fact that i want to send an email out.  Then use a Job that runs every so often to check that table and send those emails out.  I think I understand now. Thank you very much.  Will you post an answer so I can give credit where credit is due?

Comment: As for the `WHERE` clause, you simply apply your conditions on `inserted` and `deleted` tables. Example, if you want to note of rows that actually changed in some column and save them in some tempMail table  you can do it with  `INSERT INTO tempMail SELECT i.* FROM inserted i INNER JOIN deleted d ON i.ID = d.ID WHERE i.SomeColumn <> d.SomeColumn`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **cursor** inside a trigger is a very very bad idea.

A trigger should be very lean - it shouldn't do a lot of work! I would recommend to only "take a note" of who you have to send an e-mail to - but leave the actual sending of the e-mail to a separate e.g. SQL Server Agent Job which is not part of the trigger.

Triggers are fired often and often unexpectedly - don't put a log of processing burden into them! And especially not a performance killer like a cursor!

To find those rows that you're interested in, you can use a `WHERE` clause something like:

```
WHERE inserted.ColumnName <> deleted.ColumnName
```

In the context of an `UPDATE` trigger, this means the new value of `ColumnName` is different from the old value --> this column has been updated.